# Where is the model association made?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

Here is my data structure:

```
class Report < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :keywords
end

class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :report
end
```

When a `Report` is created, Keyword data is retrieved from a third party API.

```
def create
    @report = Report.new(params[:report])
    @report.get_keywords    
    create!
  end
```

The `Report` model interacts with a service object which returns third party data. The data should then be converted to `keywords` and an association should be made to the newly created `Report`.

Should the `keywords` be created in the `Report` model after the data is retrieved? Is the association made there as well?

**Edit:** Here is my Report model. How do I create an association from inside a model?

```
def get_keywords
    data = ThirdPartyDataFetcher.new.fetch_keywords
    create_keywords(data)
  end

  private

  def create_keywords(data)
    data.each do |key, value|
      keyword = Keyword.new
      keyword.description = key
      keyword.total_value = value
      # An association should be made and the keyword should be saved
      self.keywords << keyword
      keyword.save
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a design point of view fi no Keyword can live without a Report, Report should hold the logic to manage them. So the answer to your question is yes, keywords should be created inside the Report class as well as the association.

Comment: How would the association be made from within a model class? I've only made associations from controllers

Comment: @mnort9 ... `self.keywords << the_keyword_generator`, or `=`, or whatever. Although if it's coming from an API I'd probably have some way of injecting the keyword generation method.

Comment: What do you mean? In Report class you have a reference to the Keywords collection and you can use it. Something like:
self.keywords = 'key1'

Comment: Please see my edit. I don't understand exactly how to make the association.

Comment: self.keywords << keyword this is the only thing that you need. Rails know that keyworks is related to the current report and save them.